# Rundeck details of scheduled job

Tags: scheduler, jobs, rundeck

In rundeck (OpenSource v3.3.1 with H2SQL) is there any way to review the details of a Scheduled JOB? For us it is important to know the list of nodes where the job will be executed. I have searched in files and in H2 DB and I can´t get the nodes or the filter used to schedule the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that on the "Activity" [panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvmGr.jpg), click on any execution (scheduled or not), and [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYMUv.jpg) on "Log Output" you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vBsc.jpg) all job detailed info. Also, you can check the execution logs, usually at `/var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/<projectname>/job/<job-id>/logs` path.

You can check more about this [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/07-executions.html#executions).

**UPDATE 1:** you can use the [forecast API call](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#get-job-forecast) to check the jobs "to be executed", I leave a script that uses it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#############################################
echo "Insert the Rundeck Server hostname:"; read -r rundeckServer
echo -e "\nWhich port?:"; read -r rundeckPort
echo -e "\nCopy and Paste the Rundeck API Token:"; read -r rundeckApitoken

#############################################
# to run unatended mode, please comment the code above and uncomment the code below, and replace with your props
#############################################
# rundeckServer="node01.rundeck.local"
# rundeckPort="4440"
# rundeckApitoken="P0K0EvIAoWkAbmvj3JnlelmwaVhF5AJd"
#############################################
# Options Variables
#############################################
rundeckProtocol="http"
rundeckApiversion="31"
rundeckApiformat="json"
curlOptions="-s"
#############################################
echo
echo "The following Jobs are Scheduled:"
echo

for projectName in $(curl -X "GET" "$curlOptions" -H "Accept: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "Content-Type: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rundeckApitoken" "$rundeckProtocol"://"$rundeckServer":"$rundeckPort"/api/"$rundeckApiversion"/projects|sed 's/,/\n/g'| grep name | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d '"')
    do
        for jobId in $(curl "$curlOptions" -X "GET" -H "Accept: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "Content-Type: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rundeckApitoken" "$rundeckProtocol"://"$rundeckServer":"$rundeckPort"/api/"$rundeckApiversion"/project/"$projectName"/jobs | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep id | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d '"')
            do
                output=$(curl "$curlOptions" -X "GET" -H "Accept: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "Content-Type: application/$rundeckApiformat" -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rundeckApitoken" "$rundeckProtocol"://"$rundeckServer":"$rundeckPort"/api/"$rundeckApiversion"/job/"$jobId"/forecast?time=7d | grep "futureScheduledExecutions")
                if [ -n "$output" ]
                    then
                        echo $output | sed -r 's/.+("href":".+),.+("futureScheduledExecutions":\[.+\]),.+("project":".+),("name":".+).+/\1\n\3\n\4\n\2/g'
                        echo
                fi
        done
done
```

**UPDATE 2:** I leave more simple forecast API call, (require [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)).

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:4440/api/35/job/your-job-id/forecast' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: your-user-token' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '' | jq
```

That prints all info:

```
{
  "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/35/job/328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "id": "328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "scheduleEnabled": true,
  "scheduled": true,
  "enabled": true,
  "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "group": null,
  "futureScheduledExecutions": [
    "2020-08-06T14:33:00Z"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
  "name": "ExampleJob"
}
```

**UPDATE 3:** Now combining the export job info and forecast API Call, you can get the job info and the nodes, I leave an example script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#####################################################
# rundeck instance values
server="localhost"
port="4440"
api="35"
jobid="328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98"
token="MhloqezoV3IygvOIA6yzE9TNlzYCbi4m"

info=$(curl -s --location --request GET "http://$server:$port/api/$api/job/$jobid/forecast" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:$token" --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq)

nodes=$(curl -s --location --request GET "http://$server:$port/api/$api/job/$jobid" --header "Accept: application/xml" --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:$token" --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --data-raw "" | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<filter>)[^<]+")

echo "######################"
echo "Job information: $info"
echo "######################"
echo "Nodes: $nodes"
echo "######################"
```

With the following data:

```sh
######################
Job information: {
  "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/35/job/328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "id": "328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "scheduleEnabled": true,
  "scheduled": true,
  "enabled": true,
  "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/328789d1-986f-4aa2-9013-de8eb6b6df98",
  "group": null,
  "futureScheduledExecutions": [
    "2020-08-07T14:33:00Z"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
  "name": "ExampleJob"
}
######################
Nodes: localhost
######################
```

**UPDATE 4:** The job definition data are "distributed" on the database (H2 or anything else). So, for example, if you configure Rundeck against [MySQL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#using-mysql-as-a-database-backend) and you access the database using any tool, the node filter is [saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnf2Q.jpg) in `scheduled_execution` table.

Comment: Once the job scheduled is executed I can check de details, but when is scheduled but no executed (for example, planned to execute the job tomorrow morning only over a set of nodes), I can´t check de details of nodes where the job will be executed.
Is there a kind of plugin, file or table in database where I could check the nodes of the schedule?

Regards!

Comment: Sure! Using Forecast API endpoint, I updated my answer. Regards!

Comment: Thanks but when I execute the script only write "The following Jobs are Scheduled:" and there are scheduled jobs. It could be an API problem configuration because if I make a curl to (hostname is for example) "http://myrundeckserver:4440/api/31/ping" I get a 404 response (also I have checked with different versions of API). It´s the first time I use the API of rundeck...could you guide me to get a correct response?

Comment: Now I get the following error:
# curl -X "GET" -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: (apitoken)" http://myrundeckserver:4440/rundeck/api/35/ping

{"error":true,"apiversion":35,"errorCode":"api.error.invalid.request","message":"Invalid API Request: /rundeck/api/35/ping"}

Comment: Now I get a correct "pong" response and I have modified the script to my configuration of rundeck but I get an empty response of the script execution.

Comment: I think that I have the reason why the script is not responding, the line "output=$(curl ...| grep "futureScheduledExecutions")" doesn´t respond anything because there is not "futureScheduledExecutions" in the response:

{"href":"http://myrundeckserver:4440/rundeck/api/35/job/d30df42c-...","id":"d30df42c-...","scheduleEnabled":true,"scheduled":false,"enabled":true,"permalink":"http://myrundeckserver:4440/rundeck/project/exampleProyect/job/show/d30df42c-...","group":"WAS-IHS","description":"IFIX for WAS v7","project":"exampleProyect","name":"IFIX-WAS_7"}

Comment: I added a new update with a more simple example to call the API call. Optionally uses JQ tool to "beautify" the output. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update but in the print info doesn´t appear the detail of the nodes where the job will be executed. I mean, if I have a job and a complete list of nodes (env=[DEV|PRE|PRO]) and I want to schedule the execution over a list of nodes (for example, "env: PRE" nodes), from the job is scheduled till is executed I can´t check the nodes where will be executed the job.

Comment: I added a new update (update 3) :-) combining the forecast API call with node definition API call, at least you can see the job node filter. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! But with that calls I can get the default node filter that is defined in the job, but if I schedule the job with "Override Node Filter" and set another node, or list/regexp of nodes, actually I can´t get this information, the detail of the nodes where will be executed the scheduled job until the scheduled job is executed.

Comment: I see, right now there is no endpoint where you can get that information (because basically, rundeck will not know if it will run on the nodes until it runs, I mean, perhaps some node goes down or there is a connection failure, so, the closest way is to extract the filter from job definition [update 3]).

Comment: Thanks for your help! You have confirmed my suspicions about it and I have started learning about API calls in rundeck with your comments. Regards!

Comment: Sorry, one more question about this issue. I understand that rundeck will not know the nodes until it runs but the node, list of nodes or regexp configured in "Override Node Filter" section of the job is saved in somewhere (files, database..)? Thanks in advance and sorry about the inconvenience. Regards!

Comment: No worries, I updated the answer (update 4). Hope it helps!