# Find Upcoming Rundeck Job name & ID using API Call?

Tags: python, azure-devops, rundeck, pagerduty

I am creating a rundeck-api to findout which jobs will be running in next X hours
I am executing the python script from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Below is the script

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

api_token = '$(api_token)$' 
project_name = '$(project_name)$'

api_url = "https://infosys:4443/api/19/project/{}/jobs".format(project_name)

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token": api_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=False)

if response.status_code == 200:
    scheduled_jobs = response.json()
    current_time = datetime.now()
    three_hours_from_now = current_time + timedelta(hours=3)
    upcoming_jobs = []
    for job in scheduled_jobs:
        if 'schedule' in job and 'nextRunAt' in job['schedule']:
            next_run_at = datetime.strptime(job['schedule']['nextRunAt'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
            if current_time <= next_run_at <= three_hours_from_now:
                upcoming_jobs.append((job['name'], next_run_at))
    if upcoming_jobs:
        print("Upcoming jobs in the next 3 hours:")
        for job_name, next_run_at in upcoming_jobs:
            print("Job Name: {}, Next Scheduled: {}".format(job_name, next_run_at))
    else:
        print("No jobs scheduled in the next 3 hours.")
else:
    print("Error fetching scheduled jobs:", response.text)
```

My ADO Pipeline

```
trigger: none
stages:
- stage: Create
  pool: 
   name: sadasdadsdasd
   demands:
    - agent.name -equals sadasdadsdasd
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Building!
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          pip install requests
          pip install --upgrade requests
          pip3 install simplejson
      displayName: PIP
    - task: replacetokens@5
      inputs:
        rootDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rdjob/'
        targetFiles: 'devcheck.py'
        encoding: 'auto'
        tokenPattern: 'custom'
        tokenPrefix: '$('
        tokenSuffix: ')$'
        writeBOM: true
        actionOnMissing: 'warn'
        keepToken: false
        actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
        enableTransforms: false
        enableRecursion: false
        useLegacyPattern: false
        enableTelemetry: true

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'python devcheck.py'
```

I have few jobs which will be running in every 2 hour 40 min My expectation was to display that job name and ID .
currently its saying No jobs scheduled in the next 3 hours.
All my Jobs have timezone as UTC

Can you please let me know what changes I need to do achieve it.

PS:- I referred
[RunDeck Documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/#system-info)

But no Luck

Comment: Hi, I think that the best approach is to use the [forecast API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/#get-job-forecast) endpoint, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63267619/10426011) as an example (in bash but perfectly translatable to Python). A good idea could be to get the first forecast time and compare it with the current time and the "three hours for now" variable. Now, the advantage here is that you can get the job name and id directly from the JSON response ("id" and "name" attributes).

Comment: Hi there, As far as I understand from the YAML pipeline definition, `replacetokens@5` task simply replaced `$(api_token)$` and `$(project_name)$` in your python script file with the pipeline variable values. The script file `devcheck.py` was located in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ **rdjob**; then the pipeline execute the Bash command `python devcheck.py`.

Comment: Since the `Bash@3` was not defined with `workingDirectory`, it should be running the script `devcheck.py` from the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` rather than from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rdjob`. May I know wether this was expected or you hadn't share the `workingDirectory` property of the `Bash@3` task? Or maybe there were 2 python script files from both `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rdjob`? Have you observed any error in the pipeline logs?

Comment: In addition, may I know if the issue is reproducible when running the **same** python script without using pipeline to call this API? This issue is tagged with `Azure DevOps`, but I am not sure it is caused by Azure DevOps pipelines. The information could help narrow down the cause of the issue for further investigation. Thx.